# MSQL ROW Fetching time. Taking more than 5 minute to return 6000 rows

Tags: mysql

When executing a query , it took 5 minute or more to get the result which is 6000 rows. Is it a normal time ? Will it take 5 minute return 6000 rows?

Comment: And what is that query ?

Comment: We cannot tell without knowing more: which server, which operating system, which version of MySQL, which database schema, which indexes, which SQL query etc... Please edit your question to improve it. And give output of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html)

Comment: Need waaaay more info that that please. At the very least we need the SQL to be able to see what kind of call is going on to these 6000 rows.